# Mirroring Facebook comments on website using Disqus comment system

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments, disqus

I read about the possibility to mirror Facebook comments. The idea is that when you share a link from your website to your Facebook page, comments on your webpage will also appear as comments on your Facebook post and vice versa. https://developers.facebook.com/products/social-plugins/comments/

I'm wondering if it's possible to do the same thing using the Disqus comment system? That means for any Facebook post that is a link to my website, is it possible to show the comments on that post on my website too using the Disqus comment system?

I know it's possible with LiveFyre but I don't want to switch my comment system ...

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible. The Facebook Comment Mirroring uses the Facebook Comments plugin. So the comments on your site, using the plugin, will also appear on the Facebook Post that the publisher has shared (and linked via a special API).

It is not possible to make the comments using the Disqus plugin appear on the Facebook post. They don't support that special integration.